# How to use beautiful soup to extract elements from collapsible section

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm developing a python scraper using beautiful soup4 and I have difficulty to scrape the information in a collapsible section in this page: https://www.redfin.com/CA/Los-Angeles/1366-W-22nd-St-90007/home/6896268.

The collapsible section I want to scrape is "Property History for 1366 West 22nd St". The information I'm trying to get is "date" column and "price" column.

```
url = "https://www.redfin.com/CA/Los-Angeles/1366-W-22nd-St-90007/home/6896268"

headers = { 'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)'}
req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers = headers)
res = urllib.request.urlopen(req, context=ssl.SSLContext())
soup = BeautifulSoup(res, 'html.parser')

dates = [td.text for td in soup.find_all('td', {"class": "date-col nowrap"})]
```

However, the dates I scraped from date column only have Oct 29, 2018, Aug 24, 2018 and Aug 24, 2018, because `soup.find_all('td', {"class": "date-col nowrap"})` cannot find the rest dates after these three dates. The rest dates are collapsed and need to click "See all property history" button to unfold the rest dates. Is there any way to scrape the collapsed dates using Selenium?

Comment: one option is to use Selenium as it looks like the page is rendered after the initial request, but as you stated, would like to stay away from Selenium. The other option is to find where that data is requested from. I'm looking into that at the moment to see if I can find that.

Comment: FYI Accessing the redfin.com in an automated fashion is a violation of T&C

Comment: @QHarr, oh good catch. I didn't even check the T&C and I should have.

Comment: @chitown88 just updated, the method using Selenium is okay.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code which should work, it returns the table as a dictionary of tuples.

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
import time

url = "https://www.redfin.com/CA/Los-Angeles/1366-W-22nd-St-90007/home/6896268"

def browser():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(url)
    return driver

def main():
    driver = browser()
    el = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[contains(text(), "See all property history")]')
    el.click()
    # should expand quite quickly, otherwise might need to wait, e.g. time.sleep(5)
    row_arg = "//tr[@class=' PropertyHistoryEventRow']" # take note of the space before 'Property'
    rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(row_arg)
    tbl = {}
    for i, row in enumerate(rows):
        date = row.find_element_by_xpath('.//td[@class="date-col nowrap"]').text
        event = row.find_element_by_xpath('.//td[@class="event-col"]').text
        price = row.find_element_by_xpath('//td[@class="price-col number"]').text
        appre = row.find_element_by_xpath('.//td[@class="appreciation-col number empty"]').text
        tbl[i] = (date, event, price, appre)
    for k, v in tbl.items():
        print(k, v)

    return tbl
```